# SidebarListStyle no longer displays collapse/expand buttons - Xcode 15 beta 6

Tags: swiftui, ios17

With a `List` embedded in a `VStack`, in iOS 16 adding a `.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())` would add the collapse/expand buttons to each `Section`. Running Xcode 15 beta 6 and the buttons are no longer displayed on each Section. I found the following New Feature in Apple's documentation for SwiftUI, not sure if it's the root cause.

From [iOS & iPadOS 17 Beta 6 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-ipados-17-release-notes):

> Lists using the SidebarListStyle hosted in primary column of a UIKit UISplitNavigationController were previously rendering with an insetGrouped appearance. With this change they will render as the expected sidebar appearance similar to if the List were hosted in a SwiftUI NavigationSplitView. (96909195)

Is there any other `listStyle` that will add these collapse/expand buttons back or is this a potential bug in Xcode's beta? Hoping to not make custom section headers.

```
            List {
                ForEach(searchResults, id: \.Id) { log in
                    if log.logs?.count ?? 0 > 0 && vm.filterLogs(logs: log.logs!).count > 0 {
                        Section(header: Text(vm.getSectionText(log: log))
                            .font(.title3)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .foregroundColor(.primary),
                                content: {
                            ForEach(vm.filterLogs(logs: log.logs!), id: \.Id) { record in
                                Button(action: {
                                    vm.selectedLog = log
                                    vm.selectedRecord = record
                                    isShowingDetailSheet.toggle()
                                }, label: {
                                    RecordView(record: record)
                                })
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
```

I have tried other `listStyle` options, but none of them add the collapse/expand buttons.

Comment: iOS 16 to 17, Xcode 15 beta 6, what a mess of numbers. This rant goes to Apple... Seriously, as a test, if you give iOS16 (instead of 17) as a minimum deployment target in your project, does that change something?

Comment: @soundflix - Changing the minimum deployment does not change anything. I provided the version of Xcode beta I'm using, which is 15 beta 6 and simply stated that in iOS 16 this behavior worked.

Answer (score 2):

There's a [new initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/section/init(isexpanded:content:header:)-561d7) for `Section` in iOS 17, which takes a boolean Binding `isExpanded`. This value, together with the `.sidebar` list style, brings back the arrow and functionality to expand/collapse the section.

Here's a small example:

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    @State var isExpanded = true
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(isExpanded: $isExpanded) {
                Text("one")
                Text("two")
                Text("three")
            } header: {
                Text("Section Title")
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.sidebar)
    }
}
```

[image: Preview of the example code]

In your case, however, you would need to find a way to have one binding for each of your `log` items.